# Construct an example in which $x$ is $\tau_1$-accumulation point of a subset $A$ of $X$ but It is not $\tau_2$-accumulation point of $A$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be a topologies on a set $X$ with $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ Construct an example in which $x$ is $\tau_1$-accumulation point of a subset $A$ of $X$  but It is not $\tau_2$-accumulation point of $A$

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: Think in extremes.

Comment: $X=\{1,2  \} A=  \{1\} \tau_1$ is the indiscrete topology and $\tau_2$ is the discrete topology. Is it  correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct the point $2$ would be the point in question.

Comment: Exactly, thanks